# Reference a shared inbox account

Tags: vba, outlook

On a shared inbox account, I would like to run a script if the email is unread.

I tried this:

```
Sub UnreadMail()

 Dim myEmail As Object
 Dim myNamespace As Object
 Dim myFolder As Folder

 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each myEmail In myFolder
 If (myEmail.UnRead) Then
  Call SaveAttachToDisk
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You almost got it, Try using `GetSharedDefaultFolder` Look at MSDN *[GetSharedDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220116%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**

```
Option Explicit
Sub UnreadMail()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim olShareInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olShareName = olNameSpace.CreateRecipient("Om3r@Email.com") 'address
    Set olShareInbox = olNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox) 'Inbox


    For Each olItem In olShareInbox.Items
        If (olItem.UnRead) Then
            'Call SaveAttachToDisk
            Debug.Print olItem '// Print UnRead Item to Immediate window
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```