# How to extract email on receive/send to/from shared mailbox in outlook vba?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have 20 shared mailboxes in my current outlook application. I tried extracting and displaying email by using ItemAdd and ItemSend for current outlook profile which is my personal (nvreddy@domain.com) and succeeded. but when I am tried for shared mailboxes I got failed and no idea where to start to get extraction of email receive and send for share mailboxes.

how can I make sure Outlook VBA to identify and display if any new email receives to any shared mailbox and sends from any shared mailbox. I hope I have explained my best here as I am new bee here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952936/4539709

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder) method to get a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user.

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
 Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

As soon as you have retrieved an instance of the `Folder` class you can add an `ItemAdd` event handler.

The `ItemSend` event is fired only for the accounts configured in your profile.

Comment: Thank you for addressing but ...

Set sharedemail = objectNS.CreateRecipient("Viswanathareddy.Nitturu@conduent.com") **Set sentitem = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedemail, olFolderSentMail).Items** bold line throwing error as "Run time error '-2147024809(80070057).

would you please advice as difficulty in accessing the Shared sent items as Shared inbox is easy way with your approach.

Comment: sorry for delayed response I have tried resolving this issue but no luck. as of now due other things I have parked it. definitely I will try and let you know.