# How to run code on second inbox (shared account)?

Tags: vba, outlook

I move an email to a specific subfolder of the inbox as soon as it has been tagged with the tag "Invoice".

```vb
Private WithEvents objInboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
Private WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

'Process inbox mails
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInboxFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInboxFolder.Items
End Sub

'Occurs when changing item
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objTargetFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
       Set objMail = Item
 
       'Move mails based on color category
       If InStr(objMail.Categories, "Invoice") > 0 Then
          Set objTargetFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Invoices").Folders("Uploaded")
          objMail.Move objTargetFolder
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have two mailboxes/accounts in Outlook. My personal email address as well as Accounting@company.com (used by multiple people).

How do I address the Accounting inbox?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952936/4539709

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method of the [NameSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace) object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

So, you can enumerate stores in the Outlook profile and find the required one. For example, the following code shows how to iterate over all stores and folders in Outlook recursively:

```
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
   EnumerateFolders oRoot 
 Next 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub EnumerateFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder) 
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders 
 Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim foldercount As Integer 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set folders = oFolder.folders 
 foldercount = folders.Count 
 'Check if there are any folders below oFolder 
 If foldercount Then 
   For Each Folder In folders 
     Debug.Print (Folder.FolderPath) 
     EnumerateFolders Folder 
   Next 
 End If 
End Sub
```

You can check out the [Store.DisplayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.displayname) property to find the required store in the profile and then get the required inbox folder of the specific store in Outlook.